# Batch update column in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update a specific column for all rows in a table in phpMyAdmin.

I use this:

```
UPDATE jk_m1_users SET group = '2' WHERE group = '1'
```

However I get this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column1 = 2 WHERE column1 = 1' at line 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is MySQL's reserved word. Since you called your column like that, you now need to put backticks around it every time you use it.

```
UPDATE jk_m1_users SET `group` = '2' WHERE `group` = '1'
```

For a full list of reserved words follow [this finely crafted link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) (choose your MySQL version from menu on the left for better accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

That query seems to be fine... what is the REAL query you're running? Maybe the table name is a reserved word? Maybe column1 or column2 are from a different type rather than a char?

**Edit:**

As `group` is a reserved word you should use backticks to reference it:

```
UPDATE jk_m1_users SET `group` = '2' WHERE `group` = '1'
```

However, I'd recommend not using that general name in a column.

Comment: My actual query is: UPDATE jk_m1_users SET group = '2' WHERE group = '1'

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word. Surround it with back ticks.

Comment: I wouldn't use group as a column name. Remember `group by`... I would rename it

Comment: No need to rename them, just *always* quote fields and table names with backticks. There are 100+ reserved words and with every new version of mysql new ones are added.

Comment: It is not a need, but having to backtick columns it's a pain in the neck, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Updated due to fresh information on the field names

```
UPDATE jk_m1_users SET `group` = 2 WHERE `group` = 1;
```

Comment: I changed it to: UPDATE jk_m1_users SET group = 2 WHERE group = 1, but the error persists.

Comment: @yann check the comment above, have updated answer to reflect